# how to get day, month and year from date function in php?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I am getting data in my php variable from database:

```
var_dump("The schedule is: ".$my_Schedule);
```

I am getting this output:

```
string(37) "Reviews created : 2019-10-19 03:47:57"
```

Now I want to use this data to show something like:

```
// My Desired Result
Oct 01, 2019
```

I don't want time here.

I am doing it like this:

```
<p><?=date('Y-m-d',$my_Schedule);?></p>
```

This is not working for me.

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong.

Any idea or suggestion would be helpful.

Thank You.

Comment: You tagged this with CakePHP. Are you using Cake? If so, what version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use following code

```
echo date('M d,Y',strtotime('2019-10-19 03:47:57'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$date = date('M d, Y', strtotime('2019-10-19 03:47:57'));
echo $date;
// output Oct 19, 2019
```